# Card flip jquery flipping both cards at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, card-flip

This is my first time attempting card flip coding. I got it to work, but now I have two things I'd like to do that I can't get:

1. I want each card to flip separately when the respective card is clicked.
2. I'd like for the image card to be mobile responsive.

```js
function flip() {
  $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

```css
.cardContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 484px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-perspective: 400px;
  -moz-perspective: 400px;
  -o-perspective: 400px;
  perspective: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="cardContainer">
  <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="front"><img src="http://little.convio.net/images/content/pagebuilder/Alyssa_front.jpg" width="400" /></div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="cardContainer">
  <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="front"><img src="http://little.convio.net/images/content/pagebuilder/Alyssa_back.jpg" width="400" /></div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[See jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justicia118/qsQun/908/)

[Website where it's being used](https://secure3.convio.net/little/site/SPageServer;jsessionid=00000000.app334b?pagename=GameChangers_Holiday2016&NONCE_TOKEN=6FC915C90F2E51E55F0E93E8602B0563)

I am not a web designer/developer so my coding experience is pretty limited.  This is the last piece of the puzzle to get this page finished. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage your click events in your main script and, when click is fired, apply the `toggle` on the closest `.card` of the event target.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.card').on('click', function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
});
```

```css
.cardContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 484px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-perspective: 400px;
  -moz-perspective: 400px;
  -o-perspective: 400px;
  perspective: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="cardContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="http://little.convio.net/images/content/pagebuilder/Alyssa_front.jpg" width="400" />
    </div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="cardContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="http://little.convio.net/images/content/pagebuilder/Alyssa_back.jpg" width="400" />
    </div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

For the responsive part, I suggest you use a grid system like [960 Grid System](http://960.gs%22960%20Grid%20System%22), or Bootstrap grid system.

Comment: You're script edit, worked perfectly. Thank you!I am using a grid system on the webpage, but for whatever reason, the image does not resize to fit screen. I've tried adding media queries, but nothing, unless I am just applying it to the wrong class.

Comment: I got it. I was applying the media query to the wrong class. Thanks for the help with the javascript!